# Searching for an example of classes and objects using Processing

Tags: java, class, object, processing

I am a beginner and I have little to no prior programming experience, I was hoping I could learn something. I think a ellipse would be the best object.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I have shorted the title, apologies for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume I want to build cars in Processing. I could have several variables to describe information about the car, say, the `bodyColor`, `yearMade` or `model`. However, having global variables to define these is redundant. We use **Objects** in Java (which is what Processing is made in) to define a collection of variables and methods.

A **class** is a *blueprint* for an object. You can't have an object without a class to define it from. For instance, if we want to make a `Car` object, we need to define a `Car` type. This is done using **classes**.

```
class Car //defines the class Car
{
  color bodyColor; //the body color of the car
  int yearMade; //the year the car was made
  String model; //the model of the car

  void drive() {
    //add code for making the car move here
  }

  void paint(color newColor) {
    bodyColor = newColor; //paints the car to a new color
  }
}
```

Every class can have variables, like `model`, and methods, like `drive()`.

Now remember, this is a blueprint, not an object. To make a `Car` object, the class needs something called a **constructor function.** A constructor function is something that builds the object using the information from the class.

Inside of `Car`:

```
public Car(color colorChosen, int thisYear, String modelName) {
  bodyColor = colorChosen;
  yearMade = thisYear;
  model = modelName;
}
```

We can imagine that when we call this function anywhere in our code, we are creating a new car object:

```
Car myFirstCar = new Car(color(0, 255, 0) /*green*/, 2020, "Toyota");
```

In that example, `myFirstCar` is a car that is green, made in 2020, and is a Toyota.

You can also get and set properties of objects:

```
print(myFirstCar.yearMade); //2020
myFirstCar.model = "Honda";
print(myFirstCar.model); //Honda
myFirstCar.paint(color(255, 0, 0)); //paints the car red. Now myFirstCar.bodyColor = color(255, 0, 0).
```

There are lots of great things you can do with objects. They are so important to Java, because it is the *foundation* of object-oriented programming. With time and practice, creating classes and objects will be a piece of cake.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

The answer already given by [Ben Myers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12101201/ben-myers) is a great explanation of objects and classes in general.

This answer gives a small example in Processing that could be helpful to show how you can use objects and classes in a Processing sketch:

```
// Create two moving ellipse objects that follow the mouse pointer.
// The MovingEllipse class can be found below.
MovingEllipse movingEllipse1 = new MovingEllipse(20, 2.0);
MovingEllipse movingEllipse2 = new MovingEllipse(50, 3.2);

void setup() {
  size(600, 600);
  frameRate(60);
}

void draw() {
  // Clear the previous frame and set the background color to anthracite.
  background(56, 62, 66);

  movingEllipse1.move();
  movingEllipse1.draw();

  movingEllipse2.move();
  movingEllipse2.draw();
}


class MovingEllipse {
  float x;
  float y;
  float speed;
  float fillColor;
  float ellipseWidth;
  float ellipseHeight;

  MovingEllipse(float position, float speed) {
    this.x = position;
    this.y = position;
    this.speed = speed;
    this.fillColor = 7 * speed * speed * speed;
    this.ellipseWidth = 6.0 + speed * speed;
    this.ellipseHeight = 2.0 * speed;
  }

  void move() {
    PVector direction = new PVector(mouseX - x, mouseY - y).setMag(speed);
    x += direction.x;
    y += direction.y;
  }

  void draw() {
    fill(fillColor);
    ellipse(x, y, ellipseWidth, ellipseHeight);
  }
}
```